# How to optimize mysql query getting categories and subcategories

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli

I created a script which builds a menu with categories, sub-categories and sub-sub-categories. 
To get these items I use 3 separate MySQL queries. As follows:

To retrieve the main categories:

```
SELECT id, name FROM categories WHERE parent_id=0
```

To retrieve the sub-categories for each category I use:

```
SELECT id, name FROM categories WHERE parent_id=?
```

Where the ? is the id of the parent category.
I then run the query again for each sub-category.

How can I optimise this script to use less sql queries ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? if you are fetching anyway all the categories you can just select all of them and organize them in a tree structure by saving them in an array (when you store a category you check if you already have a record for its parent and if it does you save it as a child)

Comment: REALLY  !! ARE THERE GREEN CATS IN OUR PLANET :O , Despite that +1 for ur question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this query -

categories+sub categories:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c2.id, c2.name FROM categories c1
  LEFT JOIN categories c2
    ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
WHERE c1.parent_id = 0
```

---

categories+sub categories+sub sub categories:

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c2.id, c2.name, c3.id, c3.name FROM categories c1
  LEFT JOIN categories c2
    ON c2.parent_id = c1.id
  LEFT JOIN categories c3
    ON c3.parent_id = c2.id
WHERE c1.parent_id = 0
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks. Up voted and will approve as soon as the time passes :)

Comment: Yes, this query will show only sub-categories. To show one more level add one more JOIN.

Comment: How can we write this query if we have no idea about the number of level of categories?

Answer (score 2):

Some database servers have constructs to help these operations. However, MySQL is not one of them.

There are alternative ways to store hierarchies in a database that are more efficient. For a full story, check out this article. It will introduce you to nested sets.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if you only want to the parent category of a category (result row count should be equal to the number of category/subcategory rows) :

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c2.id, c2.name 
    FROM category c1
       LEFT JOIN category c2 ON c1.parent_id = c2.id
```