# Getting All subcategories of category from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table for categories called **prod_categories** and it has the following fields

```
categoryid, catparentid, catname
```

The root categories has the parentid of 0. And Our site has the following categories.

```
Computers and mobiles
    Laptops
         Linovo
         HP
    Desktop
        Alienware
    Mobiles
        Samsung
        Sony Erricson
        Motorolla
Fashion
    ...
```

Currently we are using the below query in a loop to get the results but i am looking for a single join query that would be able to get all the subcategory results or a much better performing query/loop.

```
SELECT categoryid FROM [|PREFIX|]prod_categories WHERE catparentid= $catId
```

Comment: Did you google mysql query get sub categories :)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033915/how-to-optimize-mysql-query-getting-categories-and-subcategories

Comment: NB: L**e**novo...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to optimize mysql query getting categories and subcategories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033915/how-to-optimize-mysql-query-getting-categories-and-subcategories)

Comment: do you need to get all of them at once, or just the parents/children based on an id ?